# Is this preprocessor directive acceptable here?

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

Having a singleton `Logger` class, I feel like writing `Logger::GetInstance()` everytime a print method is called is ugly. The only solution I can think of is `#define`. Is there anything better, or is this macro justified in this situation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class Logger
{
public:

    static Logger& GetInstance();
    ~Logger();
    template <typename T>
    void   Print(const T &t);
    void   SetNewline(bool b);
    void   SetLogging(bool b);

private:

    Logger();
    Logger(const Logger&);
    void operator=(const Logger&);

    bool newline;
    bool log;
    std::ofstream file;
};

int main()
{
    #define logger Logger::GetInstance()
    logger.Print("Hello");
    //Logger::GetInstance().Print("Hello");
}
```

Comment: Why do you `#define` the logger inside the `main` method? `#define` does not respect scopes. If you only want the `logger` available there, you can also do `Logger& logger = Logger::GetInstance()`.

Comment: have every object that needs to log, call GetInstance() in the constructor and store the reference?

Comment: A bit off-topic but I prefer to pass the `Logger` as an argument to any function that is in need of logging. The single point the logger is created would be the main function. I dislike globally availble modifiable state.

Comment: @Onur I'll think about that. There's a reason this is just my playground of made-up exercises, and I'm no systems designer yet... :)

Comment: If you make the `Logger` class an interface (i.e. abstract) and pass as Reference/(Smart)Pointer you can easily mock the Logger for unit tests etc. You'll also have no lifetime issues (think of a case where another static singleton outlives the logger but want's to log something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two alternatives to Cheers and hth. - Alf's answer:

You could give the logger a name, if you need it more than once in a scope:

```
Logger& logger = Logger::GetInstance();

// ...

logger.Print("Hello, world");
```

Or you could make the logging methods static as well:

```
static void Logger::Print(const T &t) {
   Logger::GetInstance().Print(t);
}
```

and then call them statically:

```
Logger::Print("Hello world!");
```

You could argue that for the client it should not matter if there actually is an instance or not - the constructor is private so they can't create their own instance anyway. So whether the static methods create an instance or not should be none of their concern. In this case, having a public method called `GetInstance` actually exposes irrelevant implementation details.

Comment: the static Print method approach is the best one of all proposed so far.

Comment: Wow. Storing the reference didn't even occur to me, I immediatly thought, okay, can't have an assignment here. That's quite clear then, thank you.

Comment: @Onur Yeah, as I'm thinking about this, is there any situation, where you have a singleton class, but you can't have it's methods static?

Comment: If you're willing to create a singleton class in the first place, I don't see why it could not have a static interface. [..] The rest of this comment became a bit long, so I added it to the answer instead.

Comment: @Innkeeper You can always have a static only interface since the only data involved is accessible via a static method.

Answer (score 4):

note, since you're apparently defining a macro "locally", that **macros do not respect scopes**.

why not just define a function instead of a macro:

```
inline
auto logger() -> Logger& { return Logger::GetInstance(); }
```

then you can write just

```
logger().Print( "Hello" );
```

Comment: +1, but why the trailing return type? I don't think it serves a purpose here.

Comment: i use that as a **single** and **unified** function declaration syntax. why use more than one syntax?

Comment: Hm, yeah, better, but still the function calling syntax. Yes, I know macros don't respect scopes, I just put it there for the question to be clear.

Comment: @angew Agree. If no type deduction required, that is totally unnecessary.